# How to correct convexity to get a perfect square in opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, transformation, opencv3.0

I am trying to correct the shape of this flat cylinder ABCD. The line AD and BC are convex and I am wondering how I could transform them to make them straight and get a square as the yellow one in the picture. Any Ideas? Thanks[image: ![here is the image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9uiQ.png)

Comment: Try some image morphing.. It would be somewhat difficult as you have round edges here..

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I tried some image transformation, but it did not work, any others suggestions?